# I am not able to use IF and EXPECT in Protractor and Jasmine

Tags: typescript, protractor, e2e-testing, browser-automation

Here's a situation.

```
if (await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(this.collapsedContinent), 500)) {
            await this.helper.click(this.expandCountry);
            await this.helper.click(this.chkcountry);
        } else {
            await this.helper.click(this.chkcountry);
        }
```

I am expecting my expect to return a true or false and then do the subsequent actions. Looks like I am doing something wrong here.

I know that expect returns a promise but is there anyway I can have expect return a true or false and then go from there?

I am ok with other approach as well as long as it checks the presence of the element. I am using async await so I don't want a doThis.then(doThat);

I totally want to avoid .then()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `isPresent()` method to implement the following flow, because right now the `else` condition will never happen.

The `presenceOf` will fail after 500ms if there is no element present in DOM.

**SOLUTION:**

```
    if (await this.collapsedContinent.isPresent()) {
      await this.helper.click(this.expandCountry);
      await this.helper.click(this.chkcountry);
    } else {
      await this.helper.click(this.chkcountry);
    }
```

Comment: This totally helped. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you really need a wait before checking, browser.wait does not return true/false, but you can achieve that with .then:

```
if (await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(this.collapsedContinent), 500).then(()=> true, err=> false)) {
    await this.helper.click(this.expandCountry);
    await this.helper.click(this.chkcountry);
} else {
    await this.helper.click(this.chkcountry);
}
```